# Custom of Children to recite selichot

Tags: halacha, selichot, children

I've heard that sefardic Children aren't obligated in reciting Selichot, would you please provide me a sefardic source (according to the ruling of Maran Rabbeinu Ovadya Yosef) for it?

Comment: Welcome Shimon Ben Asher thomsong to Mi Yodeya! Great question.

Comment: Are any children obligated in reciting anything??

Comment: Parenthetically, it is worth noting the Sefer Mekadeish Yisrael by Rav  Yisroel Dovid Harpenes, in Siman 60 - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9664&st=&pgnum=98&hilite= he asks whether one should be mechaneich his kids by taking them to selichos and notes that it should be done unless it causes them a sense of pain/distress by keeping them up late etc.  Although there is no mention of any Sefardi posek